# Regular expression to replace multibyte characters?

Tags: regex, utf-8, notepad++, multibyte

Is there something like an regular expression to replace multibyte characters with them self?

i.e. I have an large textfile with characters like this:

```
漁魚京供侠競共
```

and want to replace them like:

```
漁;
魚;
京;
供;
...
```

How can I do this, using a regular expression? I tried already:

```
(.)
```

replace with

```
\1;\n
```

but that "splits" multibyte characters (i.e. utf8) to one byte per line (so one character is over 2 lines splitted). For single-byte characters it works fine... Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Which programming environment are you using? Some regular expression engines understand UTF-8; some don't.

Comment: I tried to accomplish this with Notepad++s regexp function (similiar to SciTE). But would also happy with a solution, that using a different environment - so anything is okay, that can format the textfile like I mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [Vim](http://vim.org). I created a new file and pasted your sample text (漁魚京供侠競共) into a line. Then I typed:

> `:%s/./\0;`<kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>`/g`

This successfully separates the lines as you require.

The commands are:

- `:` - start a new command (on the vim command line)
- `%` - apply the change to the whole file
- `s///` - substitute
- `\0` - a backreference to the whole original match (could have used `(.)` and `\1` also)
- <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> - escape the next keystroke as a literal character
- `g` - replace all occurrences on each line

Comment: vim supports Unicode.  The minimal support level needed has `.` equate to a single logical character, irrespective of this or that encoding. Everything else, well, sucks.

Answer (score 2):

> Use \P{M}\p{M}* as a substitute. To match any number of graphemes, use (?:\P{M}\p{M}*)+ instead of \X+

You can use

> (?:\P{M}\p{M}*)

instead of

> (.)

in .NET.

Refer [Regex - Unicode Characters and properties](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)